Show that we have $x_1<0<x_n$ and $x_1\leq x_i \leq x_j \leq x_n$ then we have the inequality $x_n\times x_1 \leq x_i \times x_j$.
Show that we have $x_1<0<x_n$ and $x_1\leq x_i \leq x_j \leq x_n$ then we have the inequality $x_n\times x_1 \leq x_i\times x_j$.
We observe that $x_1\times x_n<0$
I tried using the rearrangement inequality, but didn't work. Then I tried using cases
If $x_j$=negative $\Rightarrow$ $x_i$=negative $\Rightarrow$ $x_j\times x_i>0$ the inequality proved
If  $x_j$=positive $\Rightarrow$ $x_i$=negative or positive, if $x_i$=positive $\Rightarrow$ $x_j\times x_i>0$ the inequality proved
I don't know what to do if $x_i$=negative. Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Take the absolute value. The numbers are both negative so the inequality swaps.

@FreeFunctor I dont really understand what do you mean...

I'm guessing you're referring to my solution here....

You have already proved what would happen if $x_i$ and $x_j$ are both positive or negative.
Assuming $x_i$ is negative and $x_j$ is positive,
$x_i>x_1→x_ix_n>x_1x_n$ because $x_n$ is positive.
As $x_n>x_j>0→x_nx_i<x_jx_i$ because $x_i$ is negative.
Hence $x_ix_j>x_1x_n$
